Using Git hooks with worktree
I've been using git worktree for a long time, but I just realized an issue with hooks.
It always seems to run hooks from the main worktree and never ones specific to the current work tree. Is there a way or a special location to store hooks to have them be able to be different per working copy?
We are putting in pre-commit hooks for our code that is programmatically added that verify some code rules. The problem is that if a hook is changed in one branch, it won't run that special hook, it is always running it from the root directory.
So example main root directory:
/Users/andrew/dev/.git/hooks

Example worktree directory:
/Users/andrew/dev/.git/worktrees/dev_branch

When running a git command, it is running hooks from /Users/andrew/dev/.git/hooks even when inside of the /Users/andrew/dev_branch directory. I was hoping it would use /Users/andrew/dev/.git/worktrees/dev_branch/hooks or something similar. I've also tried /Users/andrew/dev/.git/worktrees/dev_branch/.git/hooks.
Is there a way to have a worktree specific hooks folder?

I suppose one way you could do it is add checks in each hook to see what the current working directory is, then either continue one running the rest of the hook (for the main tree) or source the hook for the current tree.

You talk about both branches and worktrees. Like “changed in one branch”. The standard, non-configured hooks path belongs to the repository, not the branch or the worktree. I would probably add logic for finding the branch or worktree in the hook scripts themselves. Unless I need very different logic for them.

You can set the hooks path for the work tree explicitly,
git config extensions.worktreeconfig true    # once for the repo
# then in your worktree
hooks=$(`git rev-parse --git-dir`/hooks)
git config --worktree core.hookspath "$hooks"
mkdir -p "$hooks"
echo echo hi >"$hooks/post-checkout"
chmod +x "$hooks/post-checkout"
git checkout .

and the details at the git worktree manpage's configuration file section are important, you probably don't want to shared sparsity rules and almost certainly don't want bare or worktree settings.
